# xkeyval and hyperref in document class

Tags: document-classes, xkeyval

I have problem compiling a document with a custom document class. I am trying to process key-value parameters passed to my document class with `xkeyval`. I also need to use `hyperref` package. And that is where I get errors. I reduced both files to absolute (non)working minimum.

File `long-table.tex`:

```
\documentclass[lang=czech]{myclass}
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

File `myclass.cls`:

```
% my class
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2016/01/03 test class]

% Parameters
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}

\define@choicekey*+{myclass}{lang}[\value\position]{czech,english}{%
    \ifcase\position\relax
        \newcommand{\lang}{czech}
    \or%
        \newcommand{\lang}{english}
    \fi
}{%
    \PackageError{myclass}{Neplatná hodnota argumentu lang: \value}
}

\ProcessOptionsX<myclass>

\LoadClass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \lang
}

\endinput
```

Compilation always ends with error and I cannot find out why:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/Arch Linux) (rev 5238)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(/home/jirka/tmp/pokus2/long-table.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(./myclass.cls
Document Class: myclass 2016/01/03 test class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)))
(/home/jirka/tmp/pokus2/.tmp/l2iqdsbf/long-table.aux)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(/home/jirka/tmp/pokus2/.tmp/l2iqdsbf/long-table.out)
(/home/jirka/tmp/pokus2/.tmp/l2iqdsbf/long-table.out)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
c
l.7 \end{document}

?
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(/home/jirka/tmp/pokus2/.tmp/l2iqdsbf/long-table.aux))
 264 words of node memory still in use:
    2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 40 glue_spec, 1 write nodes
    avail lists: 2:19,3:4,4:27,5:8,6:18,7:1,8:2,9:13
    <</usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on long-table.pdf (1 page, 10719 bytes).

SyncTeX written on long-table.synctex.gz.Transcript written on long-table.log.

 návratová hodnota shellu 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Only thing I found is that problem is caused by loading `hyperref` package in combination with command `\ProcessOptionsX<myclass>` of `xkeyval`. When I comment out either one of them, everything works fine.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer From documentation I understand, that `\ProcessOptionsX` has three possible arguments.

Comment: Sorry, you're right

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I thought, that `\lang` will be defined after `\ProcessOptionsX<myclass>` which should process parameters of document class (at least that is what I think It does). It even works that way. Only after loading `hyperref` things goes bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command is `\val\position`, not `\value\position`!!!

`\value` expects a counter name, but `\position` is no counter here.

```
% my class
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclassnew}[2016/01/03 test class]

% Parameters
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}

\define@choicekey*+{myclassnew}{lang}[\val\position]{czech,english}{%
  \ifcase\position\relax
  \newcommand{\lang}{czech}
  \or%
  \newcommand{\lang}{english}
  \fi
}{%
  \ClassError{myclassnew}{Neplatná hodnota argumentu lang: #1}
}

\ProcessOptionsX<myclassnew>

\LoadClass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \lang
}

\endinput
```

Using the class

```
\documentclass[lang=czech]{myclassnew}
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

will output

> czechhello

Comment: I would use `\ClassError` instead of `\PackageError`. Also, the error message should not use `\value`, but `#1`. Finally, an incorrect `lang` would cause a dual error, as not `\lang` is defined under a faulty input. I know adding `\AtBeginDocument{\lang}` is just to show the value, but then one could rather use `\show\lang`.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for suggestions. I changed the Error macro name and #1. I leave the error handling to the OP